# Wp7 Launch MarketPlace Details with an url

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to launch internet explorer on the page of marketPlace details in my application with an url (which contains the id of the application) instead of using MarketplaceDetailTask for example?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, if you have the marketplace url for your app.  Then, it just amounts to embedding a link in your app that will launch the browser.

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/marketplace/" Content="Option 1"/>
```

[Navigate to URL](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-Navigate-to-an-external-URL-in-WP7)

But the question is, why direct the user to this, when using MarketplaceDetailTask will direct him right into the Marketplace where he can see the same info and be able to purchase the app directly as well?

Comment: Thank you Gambit. I found it with a more accurate research on the doc. It is important to actually make a small change in the url you gave me :'http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=yourappid' so that it redirect directly to the application "marketplace" when you launch it from a phone and to the website windows market from a computer. Thank you anyway